# Mapbox, Tracking mode consume over 50% of the CPU?

Tags: java, android, gps, mapbox

I'm using mapbox throughout my application and everything work great. It's just at one point, I need to track the user location in the map. I thought of using the location layer plugin to do so but the phone is overheating and after some check, this mode consume 50% of the phone CPU.

My question is, It's normal or my implementation is wrong ?

If the fault is on my end, how much should I expect the consommation to be ?

If it's normal, is there a way to work around this ?

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed a lot of CPU used when the location point is pulsing so I deactivated this feature:

```
LocationComponentOptions customLocationComponentOptions = LocationComponentOptions.builder(this).pulseEnabled(false).build();
```